Rotating Image Going Out of Visible Bounds When Using Affine Transformation
I am rotating an image using the Affine Transformation to create a pendulum that moves back and forth. When the image is rotated to the left, it goes outside of the visible bounds and disappears. How can I move the bounds so the image is always visible? This is the code used to rotate the image and the image I use to rotate.
Image that swings:

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // if no image set, then just draw a rectangle
    if (sprite == null) {
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, (int) getBounds().getWidth(), (int) getBounds().getHeight());
    } else {
        try {
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            if (spriteAngle != 0) {
                at.rotate(spriteAngle, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
            }
            at.scale(getWidth() * 1.0 / sprite.getWidth(), getHeight() * 1.0 / sprite.getHeight());
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawImage(sprite, at, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            g.drawImage(sprite, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }
    }
}

I have tried using the Rectangle class to create a temporary transformation to shift the bounds and translate the object. I have also tried rotating around the center and changing the image to.
The image is only in the bottom right so it is always in the bounds:

however this doesn't work as I need to extend the length of the image as time progresses.

You really need to provide a minimal reproducible example with link to image

The example below calculates the preferred size of the panel and uses that information when painting the image to determine the translation needed to center the image in the space available:
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Pendulum extends JPanel
{
    private int degrees;
    private Image image;

    public Pendulum(Image image)
    {
        this.image = image;
        setDegrees( 0 );
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();

        g2.translate(image.getWidth(this) + ((getWidth() - getPreferredSize().width) / 2), 0);
        g2.rotate( Math.toRadians( degrees ) );
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        double radians = Math.toRadians( 45 );
        double sin = Math.abs( Math.sin( radians ) );
        double cos = Math.abs( Math.cos( radians ) );
        int height = (int)Math.floor(image.getHeight(this) * cos + image.getWidth(this) * sin);

        return new Dimension(image.getWidth(this) * 2, height);
    }

    public void setDegrees(int degrees)
    {
        this.degrees = degrees;
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    String path = "pendulum.png";
                    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(Pendulum.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
                    final Pendulum r = new Pendulum(bi);

                    final JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 90, 0);
                    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
                    {
                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
                        {
                            int value = slider.getValue();
                            r.setDegrees( value );
                        }
                    });

                    JFrame f = new JFrame();
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.add(new JScrollPane(r));
                    f.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    f.pack();
                    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

